# How long does defragging using Piriform Defraggler take?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, defragment

I heard that defragging can make the computer faster. I downloaded Piriform Defraggler as they say that it's a better option than Windows' built-in defragging tool. I ran an analysis using Defraggler and these are the results:

: 4,406 Fragmented files (13.6 GB)
: 19,827 Total fragments
: 17% Fragmentation

This is my first time defragging. I saw some posts that the defragging took hours and even days. Does anyone know how to estimate the time from the analysis above? Does anyone have an estimated time? My hard drive has an 186.0 GB capacity, 78.9 used space, and 107.8 free space.

I also saw an option called "Quick Defrag." It's probably faster ("quick" defrag). Should I use it?

May I also ask if I could pause the defragging if it takes long put my computer to sleep or shutdown and continue it the next day?

Best regards,
Ronn

Comment: You cannot estimate, it depends on many things. You can stop / resume / restart defrag any time. Do a full defrag.

Comment: This depends on several factors.  We cannot provide an estimate for you, the software, will estimate that for you.  Defragging won't make a huge difference, and even then, it requires you to have massive fragmentation and 17% isn't that bad.

Answer (score 0):

"The amount of time Defraggler takes to defrag depends on several factors, such as the number of files that are fragmented, how fragmented they are and how much free space you have."

You can find some tips on how to potentially speed up defragging [here](http://support.piriform.com/hc/en-us/articles/204210424-How-to-speed-up-Defraggler)

tl;dr: Run quick defrag. Use CCleaner. Exclude restore and hibernation files. Stop the VSS service while defragging.